# How can I install NTP?

Tags: linux, apt, raspberry-pi, dpkg

**The Problem:**

I have a raspberry pi that is running linux. The system date and time are incorrect. I want to install NTP on it so that I can fix the time. All the instructions I can find anywhere say to use 'apt_get' to install NTP. However it seem like I don't have apt installed on my pi since I get the message "apt-get" not found whenever I try to use it.

**What I have done:**

I have been trying to install apt with dpkg but have been unsuccessful. I found some instruction [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=33923&p=291730) saying that I could use

```
wget http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apt/apt_0.9.7.7+rpi1_armhf.deb
```

to download a package for apt but I got a 404 error from the provided URL. I then when to http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apt/ in my browser and tried downloading  one of the available packages

Once I had a package I tried to install it using `dpkg -i apt_1.4.6_armhf.deb` but got the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive apt_1.4.6_armhf.deb (--install):
 package architecture (armhf) does not match system (armel)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt_1.4.6_armhf.deb
```

Then I found another site (archive.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apt/) that had packages that had 'armel' in the name instead of 'armhf' and dowloaded it and tried installing the new package using `dpkg -i apt_0.7.20.2\+lenny2_armel.deb`
The result was the following errors:

```
(Reading database ... 333 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack apt_0.7.20.2+lenny2_armel.deb ...
Unpacking apt (0.7.20.2+lenny2) over (0.7.20.2+lenny2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt:
 apt depends on libc6 (>= 2.7-1); however:
  Package libc6 is not installed.
 apt depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:4.3); however:
  Package libgcc1 is not installed.
 apt depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.3); however:
  Package libstdc++6 is not installed.
 apt depends on debian-archive-keyring; however:
  Package debian-archive-keyring is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package apt (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt
```

I don't know what to do now. **Do  I need to find a way to install all those missing libraries or does someone know a better way to get NTP installed?**

Comment: What does `dpkg --version` output? What about `cat /etc/debian_version`?

Comment: No `libc6`? This is not a Debian system. How come you have `dpkg`? What distribution did you install there? What is the output of `dpkg -l` ?

Comment: There's no point in looking for a different `apt` package: this is the right one for your processor. You'd need to install all those missing dependencies. But the actual solution is to use the proper package manager for your distribution, or to install Debian if Debian is what you want.

Comment: does `sudo apt-get install` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated at the top of your question (under background), you are actually trying to install `NTP`.

Your tutorials are most likely assuming you are using `Ubuntu` or other Debian-based distributions as it is the main Linux OS Set. Other comments also agree that you might be using the non-PIXEL desktop.

If you are using `Redhat` or `CentOS`, try using `yum install [program]`.

If you are using `Debian` or OS based off `Debian`, use `apt-get install [program]`, however, you do not seem to be on `Debian`

If you are using `Fedora`, use `yum install [program]`.

If you are using `OpenSUSE`, use `rpm -i [program].rpm`.

If none of these work, download the `.tar.gz` package from [here](http://www.ntp.org/downloads.html) using `wget [programlink]`, -> `unpack` -> `./configure` -> `make` -> `make install`.

Source:

https://superuser.com/questions/125933